# How to create a dot / small circle under text?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How can I make a dot under text using only CSS as shown in below picture?

[image: Picture with dot]

The picture needs to be always in middle with any length of string. 
Probably I need to use  `:before` OR `:after`? I've tried but result was awful.

Comment: What you have tried? Show us your effort.

Comment: Alredy come up with idea and its work correctly  :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A transformed pseudo element can be used to create this:

```css
body { text-align: center; }

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  line-height: 24px;
  min-width: 100px;
  background: #333;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.text::before {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 8px;
  content: '';
  width: 8px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">about</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
.char {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.char::before {
    content: '.';
    display: inline-block;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: -0.5em;
    left: 0;

    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;

}
```

After writing this question on stack i come up with idea:) Its works excatly like I want :)