# CSS how to create only one dotted/small circle or small image circle under text

Tags: html, css

The currently css design is underline.
Here is the currently design  code.

```css
ul#mainnav > li.current > a span {
  color: #e1472f;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1472f;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

I need to switch the underline to only one doc or small circle img.
I had attach the design am trying to achieve.

[image]

I had read through similar link
[How to create a dot / small circle under text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44236541/how-to-create-a-dot-small-circle-under-text)

If possible I need all the code stick with one category, like underline style coding
Appreciate your answer.
Thank you

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML within your question.

Comment: *I need all the code stick with one category* --> you mean what? the link your provided does exactly what you want. it"s a perfect duplicate for me

Comment: duplicate, this link already gives the answer. Just stick the class only to the element you need the dot attached to.